# Bottom of blog for home improvement

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog

The blog on the bottom of the home improvement page:

http://diy.blogoverflow.com/

States:

Stack Exchange © 2011

Can we fix that to be some sort of label that takes the current year, you then avoid having to update the page with the current year every time.

Comment: Looks like it's on all the site specific blogs. I'll ping SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fix for this has been pushed out and should be applied by the next build. Now there should be a simple current year added there.